# Publish Web API in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, webapi

I publish my web API in azure. I didn't create a new database in Azure. 
Can I access to my data stored in SQL Server via controllers?

The error I get when I try to run my app is :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I don't know if I have to create the database in Azure or not?

Comment: Where is your database?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to work against a SQL Azure database then yes, you need to create a Sql server and a database in this server.

You can do this via the azure portal - [Create SQL database using the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/) and specify the connection string in the web.config.

Here is a tutorial that creates a REST service using ASP.NET Web API - [REST service using ASP.NET Web API and SQL Database in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/#enable-migrations-create-the-database-add-sample-data-and-a-data-initializer)

Comment: Thx a lot I am going to check this out